# Reverse grinds and transmission won't lock into 1st gear

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, escort, bushing

I have a 2001 Ford Escort ZX2 with manual transmission. It has had noticeable play in the shifter but had no problems until suddenly the clutch just would not engage after being pushed down completely. It does have tension but when you try to put it in reverse it grinds the gear, and will not lock into 1st. Any ideas of what happened?

Comment: can you put it into gears when the engine is off?

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people put their transmission into Neutral while stopped at Traffic Lights.

If you are one of those, read on!

If you do this and let off of the clutch, the clutch engages with the engine and spins while the transmission sits still.

The light turns green, and suddenly you scramble to get the vehicle in gear so you can go.

What you do you? You stomp on the clutch and shove the stick shift into 1st Gear.

The problem is: The transmission parts are all sitting still and the clutch parts are still moving at the engine's idle RPM.

If you could hold the clutch in for 15 seconds or so, those parts will slow down and you would be able to put the transmission in gear without any grinding.

The other alternative, of course, is to leave the transmission in gear and just hold the clutch in while sitting at a traffic light. Many people frown on that approach. Granted, your foot could slip off of the clutch causing the vehicle to move into the flow of traffic. So, take that alternative approach with a grain of salt.

Comment: FYI: Going from FORWARD gears to REVERSE gears is similar in concept, except the transmission components are moving - not the clutch's.

Comment: `If you do this and let off of the clutch, the clutch engages with the engine and spins while the transmission sits still.` -- this doesn't make sense to me.  i would expect the opposite, that if the clutch pedal is released, the clutch **dis**engages from the input

Comment: There are 2 parts to the clutch: One part is free to move with the engine. The other half mounts to the transmission.

Comment: This description implies a lack of synchros, which date back to the 30's, and is not relevant to the question which says nothing about switching between reverse and forward or grinding specifically at stop lights.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 - you don't think the synchronizers wear out? They are mechanical parts like everything else. In fact, they are often made of brass, which will corrode if someone uses GL5 transmission fluid. Google it. I know what I'm talking about. Do you?

Comment: Where in this answer were synchros mentioned? At best this is incomplete and at worst it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 - you were the first person to mention synchronizers. You seem to be really confused.

Comment: Not confused at all. This answer does not address the question and implies that everyone who uses neutral at stop lights is shredding their transmissions, so I took issue with it. I'm done.